# Binary Search in Python, more elegant method?

Tags: python, binary-search

I'm switching over to Python and am practicing some basic logic flows, and I wrote a binary search function.  Is there a more elegant way to write this?  I don't like how I set the initial maxim to 10**99 for example (that was just a way to encompass any realistic list size).

```
def binary_search(val, arr, minum=0, maxim=10**99):
    if val < arr[0] or val > arr[-1]:
        return "Not in range"

    arr = arr[minum:maxim]
    middle = int(len(arr) / 2)
    maxim = len(arr)

    if val == arr[middle]:
        return middle
    elif val > arr[middle]:
        return middle + binary_search(val, arr, middle, maxim)
    else:
        return binary_search(val, arr, 0, middle)
```

Comment: Have you seen this: https://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/SortSearch/TheBinarySearch.html

Comment: This question might be better suited for [codereview.SE] than [SO].

Comment: You may have a logical error in your else statement. Should the line not be `return binary_search(val, arr, minum, middle)`, symmetrical with your `elif` branch?

Answer (score 1):

If `maxim` is going to only be used in a slice, `None` does the same thing:

```
def binary_search(val, arr, minum=None, maxim=None):
```

See:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> x[None:None]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> x[1:None]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
>>>
```

But honestly, it seems like a useless parameter unless you want to limit the search, but then you might as well do that explicitely before you when you pass the *list* (not array!) in.